# JS: Getting an image based on the page URL

Tags: javascript, html

Please forgive my ignorance; I'm an HTML guy and JS is pretty alien to me. I'm trying to create a function that would display an image based on the page URL.

For example: "page_001-e.html" would display "page_001.jpg"

I've managed to butcher this together so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("<img src=\"photos/full/"+location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)+".jpg"+"\" />");
</script>
```

Which returns:

```
 <img url="photo_000-e.html.jpg" />
```

I need to trim *-e.html* from the result. I'm working in a multilingual site so I can't rely on the *-e* to be a constant as it's the language indicator.

From Googling, it looks like I could use `str.replace` or maybe `slice` but what I don't know is how to use them nor where to go from here.

I'd appreciate any help, or any advice if I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the URL to the image with the following code, assuming there will always be a single dash:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img_url = window.location.href.split("-")[0] + ".jpg";
</script>
```

Now, you need to figure out where you want to place it.  I recommend making an `Image` object, and then appending it to a particular area in the DOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the image URL
    var img_url = window.location.href.split("-")[0] + ".jpg";

    // Create an image (not visible anywhere)
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    // Set the Image to load from your new URL
    img.src = image_url;

    // Add it to your HTML
    document.getElementById("some_id").appendChild(img);
</script>

<div id="some_id">
</div>
```

In the above code, the javascript will add the image to the div with ID "some_id".

Comment: Perfect. I modified this a little and got it to work! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to trim the value

```
location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).replace(location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).lastIndexOf("-"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

try with .replace ?

```
var path = location.pathname.replace('.html','.jpg');

document.write(path);
```

Comment: THis doesn't answer his question.  His image example doesn't have the "-e" (language indicator), but just replacing the file extension will retain the "-e".